# VBS Using createshortcut to get the name of a shortcut with spaces

Tags: vbscript

I'm struggling... used google and have come up with no answers to this one!

I have a code that I'm intending to run at user logon which will find a shortcut and update the shortcut location to reflect some network changes - but the shortcut has spaces in it and VBS won't find the full target path... HELP!!!

The current target of the shortcut is:

```
\\LANG-APPS2\Mandata\Warehouse\Programs\StartApp.exe  /sWH /ip192.168.73.124
```

But it will only return the bit up to .exe - it misses the last bit of `/sWH /ip192.168.73.124`

Here's my script:

```
On Error Resume Next

    wscript.echo "Checking Warehouse Shortcut..."
    Dim fso, folder, files, sFolder
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sFolder = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set files = folder.Files

    For each folderIdx In files
        fullname = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(folderIdx)
        Set shortcut = Shell.CreateShortcut(fullname)
        shortTarget = LCase(shortcut.TargetPath)
        shortWorkPath = shortcut.WorkingDirectory

        lnkFind = ".lnk"
        lnkSearch = instr(fullname, lnkfind)
        if lnkSearch > 0 then

            srvFind = "lang-apps2\mandata\warehouse\programs\startapp.exe"
            srvSearch = instr(shortTarget, srvFind)
            if srvSearch > 0 then

                pracFind = "Practice"
                pracSearch = instr(fullname, pracFind)
                if pracSearch > 0 then

                    wscript.echo "Warehouse Practice Shortcut Needs Updating!"
                    wscript.echo "Please wait while I sort that out for you......"
                    shortcut.TargetPath = """\\Lang-man\Warehouse\Programs\StartApp.exe /sWHPRAC /ip192.168.73.134"""
                    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "\\Lang-man\Warehouse\Programs"
                    shortcut.save
                    wscript.echo "Warehouse Practice Shortcut Updated!"
                else

                    wscript.echo "Warehouse Live Shortcut Needs Updating!"
                    wscript.echo "Please wait while I sort that out for you......"
                    shortcut.TargetPath = """\\Lang-man\Warehouse\Programs\StartApp.exe /sWH /ip192.168.73.134"""
                    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "\\Lang-man\Warehouse\Programs"
                    shortcut.save
                    wscript.echo "Warehouse Live Shortcut Updated!"
                end if
            end if
        end if

        set shortTarget=nothing
        set shortWorkPath=nothing
        set shortcut=nothing
    next
    wscript.echo "Finished"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of the [`TargetPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67.aspx) property on MSDN (bold added by me):

> This property is for the shortcut's target path only. **Any arguments to the shortcut must be placed in the Argument's property.**

Comment: Thank you - been driving me crazy... I didn't realise there was an arguments property... makes sense now I think about it!